# In JavaScript, how to delete piece when jump over in Checkers

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Two-player Chess</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: tomato;
    }
    
    canvas {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    const boardSize = 400,
      darkSqColor = "brown",
      lightSqColor = "beige",
      uiColor = "red",
      pieces = {},
      moves = [],
      board = {};

    var boardCanvas, boardCtx, uiCanvas, uiCtx, width, height,
      dragging = false,
      dragFrom, dragTo;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);


    /* SETUP */
    function init() {
      boardCanvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
      uiCanvas = boardCanvas.nextElementSibling;
      boardCtx = boardCanvas.getContext("2d");
      uiCtx = uiCanvas.getContext("2d");
      width = boardCanvas.width = uiCanvas.width = boardSize;
      height = boardCanvas.height = uiCanvas.height = boardSize;

      uiCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMousedown);
      uiCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMousemove);
      uiCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseup);



      setupPieces();
      setupBoard();
      drawBoard();
      drawPieces();
    }

    function setupPieces() {

    }

    function setupBoard() {
        let squareSize = boardSize/8;
             board.a8 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 0, piece: null };
             board.a7 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 1, piece: "r" };
             board.a6 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 2, piece: null };
             board.a5 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
             board.a4 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
             board.a3 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 5, piece: "b" };
             board.a2 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 6, piece: null };
             board.a1 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 7, piece: "b" };
             board.b8 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 0, piece: "r" };
             board.b7 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 1, piece: null };
             board.b6 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 2, piece: "r" };
             board.b5 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
             board.b4 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
             board.b3 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 5, piece: null };
             board.b2 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 6, piece: "b" };
             board.b1 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 7, piece: null };
             board.c8 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 0, piece: null };
             board.c7 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 1, piece: "r" };
             board.c6 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 2, piece: null };
             board.c5 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
             board.c4 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
             board.c3 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 5, piece: "b" };
             board.c2 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 6, piece: null };
             board.c1 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 7, piece: "b" };
             board.d8 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 0, piece: "r" };
             board.d7 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 1, piece: null };
             board.d6 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 2, piece: "r" };
             board.d5 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
             board.d4 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
             board.d3 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 5, piece: null };
             board.d2 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 6, piece: "b" };
             board.d1 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 7, piece: null };
             board.e8 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 0, piece: null };
             board.e7 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 1, piece: "r" };
             board.e6 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 2, piece:  null };
             board.e5 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
             board.e4 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
             board.e3 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 5, piece: "b" };
             board.e2 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 6, piece: null };
             board.e1 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 7, piece: "b" };
             board.f8 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 0, piece: "r" };
             board.f7 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 1, piece: null };
             board.f6 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 2, piece: "r" };
             board.f5 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
             board.f4 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
             board.f3 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 5, piece: null };
             board.f2 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 6, piece: "b" };
             board.f1 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 7, piece: null };
             board.g8 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 0, piece: null };
             board.g7 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 1, piece: "r" };
             board.g6 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 2, piece: null };
             board.g5 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
             board.g4 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
             board.g3 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 5, piece: "b" };
             board.g2 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 6, piece: null };
             board.g1 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 7, piece: "b" };
             board.h8 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 0, piece: "r" };
             board.h7 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 1, piece: null };
             board.h6 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 2, piece: "r" };
             board.h5 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
             board.h4 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
             board.h3 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 5, piece: null };
             board.h2 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 6, piece: "b" };
             board.h1 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 7, piece: null };
      moves.length = 1; // empty out moves array
      moves[0] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board)); // deep copy of board
    }


    /* EVENT HANDLING */
    function handleMousedown(e) {
      if (dragFrom) {
        dragging = true;
      }

    }

    function handleMousemove(e) {
      uiCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      if (dragging) {
        handleDrag(e);
      } else { // not dragging but hovering
        handleHover(e);
      }

    }

    function handleDrag(e) {
      let squareSize = boardSize / 8,
        player = whoseTurn(), // "b" or "r"
        lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1],
        square = getSquareByXY(e.clientX, e.clientY); // find square from mousemove event object;
      if (isValidMove(square)) {
        //currently, you can move a piecse onto ANY empty square (!lastPosition[square].piece) or an opponent's square (lastPosition[square].piece[0] !== player)
        // if so, highlight square
        uiCtx.lineWidth = 4;
        uiCtx.strokeStyle = uiColor;
        uiCtx.strokeRect(lastPosition[square].x + 2, lastPosition[square].y + 2, squareSize - 4, squareSize - 4);
        // draw line from original square
        uiCtx.lineWidth = 2;
        uiCtx.beginPath();
        let x1 = lastPosition[dragFrom].x + squareSize / 2,
          y1 = lastPosition[dragFrom].y + squareSize / 2,
          x2 = lastPosition[square].x + squareSize / 2,
          y2 = lastPosition[square].y + squareSize / 2;
        uiCtx.moveTo(x1, y1);
        uiCtx.lineTo(x2, y2);
        uiCtx.stroke();
        dragTo = square;
      } else {
        dragTo = null;
      }
    }

    function handleHover(e) {
      let squareSize = boardSize / 8,
        player = whoseTurn(), // "w" or "b"
        lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1],
        square = getSquareByXY(e.clientX, e.clientY); // find square from mousemove event object;
      // check if piece of player's color is on that square
      if (lastPosition[square].piece && lastPosition[square].piece[0] === player) {
        // if so, highlight square
        uiCtx.lineWidth = 4;
        uiCtx.strokeStyle = uiColor;
        uiCtx.strokeRect(lastPosition[square].x + 2, lastPosition[square].y + 2, squareSize - 4, squareSize - 4);
        dragFrom = square;
      } else {
        dragFrom = null;
      }
    }

    function handleMouseup(e) {
      console.log(dragTo)
      if (dragging) {
        if (dragTo === null) { //nothing happens if player tries to move to square piece is already on
          dragFrom = null;
          dragTo = null;
          dragging = false;
          return;
        }
        // make player move...
        //change game state
        let lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1],
          newBoard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lastPosition)),
          piece = newBoard[dragFrom].piece;
        //move piece
        newBoard[dragFrom].piece = null;
        newBoard[dragTo].piece = piece;
        //add another board to the moves array
        moves.push(newBoard);
        //update board/pieces display
        drawBoard();
        drawPieces();
        //reset drag variables
        dragFrom = null;
        dragTo = null;
        dragging = false;
      }
    }



    function isValidMove(square) { //return true or false

      let fromSq = dragFrom,
        fromFile = fromSq[0], //"a", "b", etc.
        fromRank = Number(fromSq[1]), //"3", "4", etc.
        fromFileNum = fromFile.charCodeAt(0), //number representation of letter
        movingPieceColor = moves[moves.length - 1][fromSq].piece,
        toSq = square,
        toFile = toSq[0], //"a", "b", etc.
        toRank = Number(toSq[1]), //"3", "4", etc.
        toFileNum = toFile.charCodeAt(0), //number representation of letter
        pieceOnToSq = moves[moves.length - 1][toSq].piece; //null, "b", or "r"

      //can't move onto square with own piece already on it
      if (pieceOnToSq === movingPieceColor) return false;
      //move onto empty square must be forward and diagonal
      if (!pieceOnToSq) {
        //moving one rank
        if (movingPieceColor === "b" && toRank === fromRank + 1 && Math.abs(toFileNum - fromFileNum) === 1) return true;
        if (movingPieceColor === "r" && toRank === fromRank - 1 && Math.abs(toFileNum - fromFileNum) === 1) return true;
        //moving two ranks
        if (movingPieceColor === "b" && toRank === fromRank + 2 && Math.abs(toFileNum - fromFileNum) === 2) {
          //is there a red piece to jump over?
          let jumpedSq = String.fromCharCode(fromFileNum + (toFileNum - fromFileNum) / 2) + (toRank - 1),
            jumpedPiece = moves[moves.length - 1][jumpedSq].piece;
          return jumpedPiece === "r";
        }
        if (movingPieceColor === "r" && toRank === fromRank - 2 && Math.abs(toFileNum - fromFileNum) === 2) {
          //is there a black piece to jump over?
          let jumpedSq = String.fromCharCode(fromFileNum + (toFileNum - fromFileNum) / 2) + (toRank + 1),
            jumpedPiece = moves[moves.length - 1][jumpedSq].piece;
          return jumpedPiece === "b";
        }
      }
      return false;
    }








    /* HELPERS */
    function whoseTurn() {
      // if even number of moves in moves array, it's black's turn, otherwise red's
      return moves.length % 2 === 0 ? "r" : "b";
    }

    function getSquareByXY(x, y) {
      let squareSize = boardSize / 8,
        lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1];
      for (let square in lastPosition) {
        if (lastPosition[square].x <= x && lastPosition[square].x + squareSize >= x &&
          lastPosition[square].y <= y && lastPosition[square].y + squareSize >= y) return square;
      }
    }


    /* DRAWING */
    function drawBoard() {
      let squareSize = boardSize / 8,
        isLightSq = true;
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x += squareSize) {
        for (let y = 0; y < height; y += squareSize) {
          if (isLightSq) boardCtx.fillStyle = lightSqColor;
          else boardCtx.fillStyle = darkSqColor;
          boardCtx.fillRect(x, y, squareSize, squareSize);
          isLightSq = !isLightSq;
        }
        isLightSq = !isLightSq;
      }
    }

    function drawPieces() {
      let lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1]; // get last element of moves array
      boardCtx.fillStyle = "black"; // text placeholder
      boardCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text placeholder
      boardCtx.font = "30px Verdana"; // text placeholder
      for (let square in lastPosition) { // iterate through the most recent game state
        if (lastPosition[square].piece) {
          boardCtx.fillText(lastPosition[square].piece, lastPosition[square].x, lastPosition[square].y); // text placeholder
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

I cannot figure out how to delete a piece after I jumped over it.  I am very stumped on this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I would like my red and black piece to be able to jump over the enemy and then it would be able to delete it.  I am not able to do this at this point and I cannot figure out to be able to do this.  I wonder if anyone would be able to help me.  Thank you!

Comment: A couple of tips: use nested ```for``` loop for your board setup. That's a lot of unnecessary code. Try your best to isolate the part of the code where you things are not working as intended.

Comment: Try to be more object oriented so you can build your logic in it. var Red = function(args, ..., ...) { ...build your logic} and same with Black one. Hope this helps.

Comment: You are already detecting the jump on the `isValidMove` you just have to return more out of that function, and you know how to "delete" because when you move you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, your function **isValidMove** was already doing the detection, all I did was return that jumped over piece:

```
return (jumpedPiece === "b") ? jumpedSq: false;
```

Then we collect that in a variable on your same condition on function **handleDrag** like this:

```
if (jumped = isValidMove(square)) {
```

And finally we remove it on the **handleMouseup** logic:

```
if (newBoard[jumped]) 
  newBoard[jumped].piece = null
```

That was all, I hope that was clear.
Now the comments given by others are valid, you should consider refactoring your code to be more object oriented and reduce code.

---

Here is the working solution based on your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Two-player Chess</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: tomato;
    }
    
    canvas {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    const boardSize = 400,
      darkSqColor = "brown",
      lightSqColor = "beige",
      uiColor = "red",
      pieces = {},
      moves = [],
      board = {};

    var boardCanvas, boardCtx, uiCanvas, uiCtx, width, height,
      dragging = false,
      jumped = false,
      dragFrom, dragTo;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);


    /* SETUP */
    function init() {
      boardCanvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
      uiCanvas = boardCanvas.nextElementSibling;
      boardCtx = boardCanvas.getContext("2d");
      uiCtx = uiCanvas.getContext("2d");
      width = boardCanvas.width = uiCanvas.width = boardSize;
      height = boardCanvas.height = uiCanvas.height = boardSize;

      uiCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMousedown);
      uiCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMousemove);
      uiCanvas.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseup);

      setupPieces();
      setupBoard();
      drawBoard();
      drawPieces();
    }

    function setupPieces() {

    }

    function setupBoard() {
      let squareSize = boardSize/8;
      board.a8 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 0, piece: null };
      board.a7 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 1, piece: "r" };
      board.a6 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 2, piece: null };
      board.a5 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
      board.a4 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
      board.a3 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 5, piece: "b" };
      board.a2 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 6, piece: null };
      board.a1 = { x: squareSize * 0, y: squareSize * 7, piece: "b" };
      board.b8 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 0, piece: "r" };
      board.b7 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 1, piece: null };
      board.b6 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 2, piece: "r" };
      board.b5 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
      board.b4 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
      board.b3 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 5, piece: null };
      board.b2 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 6, piece: "b" };
      board.b1 = { x: squareSize * 1, y: squareSize * 7, piece: null };
      board.c8 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 0, piece: null };
      board.c7 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 1, piece: "r" };
      board.c6 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 2, piece: null };
      board.c5 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
      board.c4 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
      board.c3 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 5, piece: "b" };
      board.c2 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 6, piece: null };
      board.c1 = { x: squareSize * 2, y: squareSize * 7, piece: "b" };
      board.d8 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 0, piece: "r" };
      board.d7 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 1, piece: null };
      board.d6 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 2, piece: "r" };
      board.d5 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
      board.d4 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
      board.d3 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 5, piece: null };
      board.d2 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 6, piece: "b" };
      board.d1 = { x: squareSize * 3, y: squareSize * 7, piece: null };
      board.e8 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 0, piece: null };
      board.e7 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 1, piece: "r" };
      board.e6 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 2, piece:  null };
      board.e5 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
      board.e4 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
      board.e3 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 5, piece: "b" };
      board.e2 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 6, piece: null };
      board.e1 = { x: squareSize * 4, y: squareSize * 7, piece: "b" };
      board.f8 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 0, piece: "r" };
      board.f7 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 1, piece: null };
      board.f6 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 2, piece: "r" };
      board.f5 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
      board.f4 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
      board.f3 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 5, piece: null };
      board.f2 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 6, piece: "b" };
      board.f1 = { x: squareSize * 5, y: squareSize * 7, piece: null };
      board.g8 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 0, piece: null };
      board.g7 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 1, piece: "r" };
      board.g6 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 2, piece: null };
      board.g5 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
      board.g4 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
      board.g3 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 5, piece: "b" };
      board.g2 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 6, piece: null };
      board.g1 = { x: squareSize * 6, y: squareSize * 7, piece: "b" };
      board.h8 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 0, piece: "r" };
      board.h7 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 1, piece: null };
      board.h6 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 2, piece: "r" };
      board.h5 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 3, piece: null };
      board.h4 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 4, piece: null };
      board.h3 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 5, piece: null };
      board.h2 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 6, piece: "b" };
      board.h1 = { x: squareSize * 7, y: squareSize * 7, piece: null };
      moves.length = 1; // empty out moves array
      moves[0] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board)); // deep copy of board
    }


    /* EVENT HANDLING */
    function handleMousedown(e) {
      if (dragFrom) {
        dragging = true;
      }
    }

    function handleMousemove(e) {
      uiCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      if (dragging) {
        handleDrag(e);
      } else { // not dragging but hovering
        handleHover(e);
      }
    }

    function handleDrag(e) {
      let squareSize = boardSize / 8,
        player = whoseTurn(), // "b" or "r"
        lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1],
        square = getSquareByXY(e.clientX, e.clientY); // find square from mousemove event object;        
      if (jumped = isValidMove(square)) {
        //currently, you can move a piecse onto ANY empty square (!lastPosition[square].piece) or an opponent's square (lastPosition[square].piece[0] !== player)
        // if so, highlight square
        uiCtx.lineWidth = 4;
        uiCtx.strokeStyle = uiColor;
        uiCtx.strokeRect(lastPosition[square].x + 2, lastPosition[square].y + 2, squareSize - 4, squareSize - 4);
        // draw line from original square
        uiCtx.lineWidth = 2;
        uiCtx.beginPath();
        let x1 = lastPosition[dragFrom].x + squareSize / 2,
          y1 = lastPosition[dragFrom].y + squareSize / 2,
          x2 = lastPosition[square].x + squareSize / 2,
          y2 = lastPosition[square].y + squareSize / 2;
        uiCtx.moveTo(x1, y1);
        uiCtx.lineTo(x2, y2);
        uiCtx.stroke();
        dragTo = square;
      } else {
        dragTo = null;
      }
    }

    function handleHover(e) {
      let squareSize = boardSize / 8,
        player = whoseTurn(), // "w" or "b"
        lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1],
        square = getSquareByXY(e.clientX, e.clientY); // find square from mousemove event object;
      // check if piece of player's color is on that square
      if (lastPosition[square].piece && lastPosition[square].piece[0] === player) {
        // if so, highlight square
        uiCtx.lineWidth = 4;
        uiCtx.strokeStyle = uiColor;
        uiCtx.strokeRect(lastPosition[square].x + 2, lastPosition[square].y + 2, squareSize - 4, squareSize - 4);
        dragFrom = square;
      } else {
        dragFrom = null;
      }
    }

    function handleMouseup(e) {
      console.log(dragTo)
      if (dragging) {
        if (dragTo === null) { //nothing happens if player tries to move to square piece is already on
          dragFrom = null;
          dragTo = null;
          dragging = false;
          return;
        }
        // make player move...
        //change game state
        let lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1],
          newBoard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lastPosition)),
          piece = newBoard[dragFrom].piece;
        //move piece
        newBoard[dragFrom].piece = null;
        newBoard[dragTo].piece = piece;
        //remove if jumped
        if (newBoard[jumped]) 
          newBoard[jumped].piece = null
        //add another board to the moves array
        moves.push(newBoard);
        //update board/pieces display
        drawBoard();
        drawPieces();
        //reset drag variables
        dragFrom = null;
        dragTo = null;
        dragging = false;
      }
    }

    function isValidMove(square) { //return true or false
      let fromSq = dragFrom,
        fromFile = fromSq[0], //"a", "b", etc.
        fromRank = Number(fromSq[1]), //"3", "4", etc.
        fromFileNum = fromFile.charCodeAt(0), //number representation of letter
        movingPieceColor = moves[moves.length - 1][fromSq].piece,
        toSq = square,
        toFile = toSq[0], //"a", "b", etc.
        toRank = Number(toSq[1]), //"3", "4", etc.
        toFileNum = toFile.charCodeAt(0), //number representation of letter
        pieceOnToSq = moves[moves.length - 1][toSq].piece; //null, "b", or "r"

      //can't move onto square with own piece already on it
      if (pieceOnToSq === movingPieceColor) return false;
      //move onto empty square must be forward and diagonal
      if (!pieceOnToSq) {
        //moving one rank
        if (movingPieceColor === "b" && toRank === fromRank + 1 && Math.abs(toFileNum - fromFileNum) === 1) return true;
        if (movingPieceColor === "r" && toRank === fromRank - 1 && Math.abs(toFileNum - fromFileNum) === 1) return true;
        //moving two ranks
        if (movingPieceColor === "b" && toRank === fromRank + 2 && Math.abs(toFileNum - fromFileNum) === 2) {
          //is there a red piece to jump over?
          let jumpedSq = String.fromCharCode(fromFileNum + (toFileNum - fromFileNum) / 2) + (toRank - 1),
            jumpedPiece = moves[moves.length - 1][jumpedSq].piece;
          return (jumpedPiece === "r") ? jumpedSq: false;
        }
        if (movingPieceColor === "r" && toRank === fromRank - 2 && Math.abs(toFileNum - fromFileNum) === 2) {
          //is there a black piece to jump over?
          let jumpedSq = String.fromCharCode(fromFileNum + (toFileNum - fromFileNum) / 2) + (toRank + 1),
            jumpedPiece = moves[moves.length - 1][jumpedSq].piece;
          return (jumpedPiece === "b") ? jumpedSq: false;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }


    /* HELPERS */
    function whoseTurn() {
      // if even number of moves in moves array, it's black's turn, otherwise red's
      return moves.length % 2 === 0 ? "r" : "b";
    }

    function getSquareByXY(x, y) {
      let squareSize = boardSize / 8,
        lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1];
      for (let square in lastPosition) {
        if (lastPosition[square].x <= x && lastPosition[square].x + squareSize >= x &&
          lastPosition[square].y <= y && lastPosition[square].y + squareSize >= y) return square;
      }
    }


    /* DRAWING */
    function drawBoard() {
      let squareSize = boardSize / 8,
        isLightSq = true;
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x += squareSize) {
        for (let y = 0; y < height; y += squareSize) {
          if (isLightSq) boardCtx.fillStyle = lightSqColor;
          else boardCtx.fillStyle = darkSqColor;
          boardCtx.fillRect(x, y, squareSize, squareSize);
          isLightSq = !isLightSq;
        }
        isLightSq = !isLightSq;
      }
    }

    function drawPieces() {
      let lastPosition = moves[moves.length - 1]; // get last element of moves array
      boardCtx.fillStyle = "black"; // text placeholder
      boardCtx.textBaseline = "top"; // text placeholder
      boardCtx.font = "35px Verdana"; // text placeholder
      for (let square in lastPosition) { // iterate through the most recent game state
        if (lastPosition[square].piece) {
          boardCtx.fillText(
            lastPosition[square].piece, 
            lastPosition[square].x + 10 , 
            lastPosition[square].y); 
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <canvas></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this problem.  Curious if someone wanted to double jump, or triple jump, or etc. etc., how could that be implemented instead of going to the next person turn?

Comment: @Jay to prevent going to the next person turn when we jump, you will need to change your logic in `function whoseTurn` to account for jumps